# Cannot resolve NavigationView even after adding the dispository

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-databinding, navigationview

So this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried using "NavigationView" and after researching i found out I need to add a new dependency to my build.gradle which I did. BUT after I tried to build my app I got the following error:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:design:22.2.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

But I've already installed the Support Repository:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `Invalidate Cache/Restart`

Comment: @Shaishav where can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error: I didn't edited the correct build.gradle file.I edited android/build.gradle instead of android/app/build.gradle......

Answer (score 0):

yes. If you want to add any library to your project, you should implement them in the `build.gradle` app there.

For reminder, the library version *for example*,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

those library is under the same library so the version all should be the same to prevent any `sync` error.